# Mascara parar solo mayusculas en maskedtextbox

Tags: vb.net

Como puedo hacer que en un maskedtextbox, el cual ya tiene una mascara asignada, y permite que se ingresen números y letras, las letras solo sean mayúsculas?

Comment: Quieres convertir todas las letras a mayusculas o obligar a que se introduzcan mayúsculas?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias agregar la mascara que estas usando?

Comment: es: 0000-0000-0000

Comment: Con esa mascara ni mayusculas ni minusculas...solo numeros.

Comment: Hola @Pikoh quiero obligar a que se ingresen solo mayusculas, pense que era de la misma forma que con un textbox pero ya me di cuenta que no

Comment: Francisco por favor agrega la informacion a a pregunta. Como dice @pikoh esa mascara no sirve para letras. Entonces quieres modificar tu pregunta o que te gustaria hacer con ella?

Comment: La pregunta es muy sencilla, pero necesito saber que mascara estás usando o exactamente cual es el formato de entrada que estás buscando. porque `0000-0000-0000` solo permitiría la entrada de digitos

Comment: pero la mascara si me deja ingresar letras.... ahora si debo cambiarla pues pruebo.. un ejemplo de dato a introducir seria: 1522-1542-MK12

Comment: Con esa mascara no puede dejarte introducir letras...pero bueno. Te respondo con lo de poner en mayusculas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para convertir todas las letras introducidas en un `MaskedTextBox` puedes añadir a la máscara un simbolo *mayor que* al principio, como se explica aqui [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx). Por ejemplo, para permitir una entrada como `1522-1542-MK12` podría ser algo como:

```
>CCCC-CCCC-CCCC
```

O, siguiendo exactamente el formato de tu ejemplo:

```
0000-0000->LL00
```

Comment: Me sirvió a la perfección! era justo lo que necesitaba muchas gracias